# Convert xml to bson

Tags: xml, json, mongodb, bson

Iam looking for a solution to convert a arbitrary xml file to bson file to import this file in a mongodb. After recherche I found some hint to convert the xml to json and then to bson. But there with come problems:

1. The means of expression in a xml format are such higher than in a json format
2. json types are only a subset of bson types

A other solution is to generate objects in some common programming language from the xml file and safe it to mongodb.

Which way you would recommend?

Comment: Arbitrary XML cannot be stored in a loss-less format as native BSON without subjecting the XML to a number of modifications. You'll need to restructure it and solve problems like the fact that there are no attributes in BSON (or JSON).

Comment: The real question though.... what are you going to do with the result when it's saved in MongoDB? Queries? Why MongoDB?

Comment: I have a relative complex and huge XML file and I like to query on it. Till now for me it looks like that the easiest way to so, is to create objects from the XML and store them in a object orientated database.

Comment: Yeh I need an answer for this too.. @WiredPrairie, we're assuming the OP already made that answer about choosing MONGODB before asking this question.. it's a real question, but not worth considering on stackoverflow as it'll go beyond the scope of what he's looking for. I'm sure there are tools for doing this well, I have an XML doc that are only nodes.. no attributes.

Comment: @sksallaj - I don't want to presume anything about the selection of a technology. It's a fair question to ask and simple enough to answer. And, they did answer that they wanted to store them in an "Object Oriented Database." MongoDB is a document DB and not object oriented. Unplanned queries can also be very inefficient. XML->JSON->Import can work, although it may not produce ideal DB results.

Comment: There are drivers for c# to bind to mongodb, you can definitely store as a document type, but you can also convert it to a collection of objects if you wanted using c#. There is no such thing as object oriented db, you can use an object oriented language on top of a db, regardless of the db type you're using, and as long as there's a driver supplied.